# How to solve $1+2^\frac12+4^\frac14+8^\frac18+16^\frac1{16}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$x=1+2^\frac12+4^\frac14+8^\frac18+16^\frac1{16}+\dots$$
I have no clue where to start hence why I'm posting this here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We note that for all $x>1$:
$$x^{1/x}>1$$
Therefore the sum diverges because every term is at least one.

Comment: how can I prove that $x^\frac{1}{x} >1$ ?

Comment: @d9ngle Start from $x>1$. Then take $x$th roots; the $x$th root of 1 remains 1.

Comment: @d9ngle Well, the exponential function $x\mapsto a^x$ is strictly increasing for $a>1$. With $a^0 = 1$ you see that $a^y>1$ for $y>0$.